# Using "first level" machine learning models to create features for a "second level" model

Tags: machine-learning, svm, random-forest, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I have learned about specific models but I want to learn more about a particular part of machine learning problem solving. I haven't been able to find papers about this, partly due to not being sure what its called.

I have a big dataset. I have trained many binary classifier models on it. I want to put the predictions of these models into a 'second level' model. In this I also want to add other features like 'do all models agree on this class' and stuff like that.

I'm not sure how much leeway I have when adding features to this second level model. Is it OK to take data features from the 'first level' model and put it in the 'second level'? Is there a name for the process of stacking models like this that someone could shed some light on? Could I repeat the process again and make a 'third level'?

Thank you

Comment: This question may be more suited for [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com). What you are looking for is called [bagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating).

Comment: Also search about "stacking" in ensemble learning.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions sound to me related to bagging , boosting and ensembles , search for them, for example "do all models agree on this class" sounds like "majority voting ensembles", and " I have trained many binary classifier models on it. I want to put the predictions of these models into a 'second level' model." sounds to me like : adaboost in which your training will give every classifier a weight(similar to how in ML you give weights to every feature) , and the output of the classifier will be the "features" ,so every classifier output will be weighted by weights also learned while training. Also if you are planning to use deep learning, theres "transfer learning" in which you use one classifier just as feature extractor and this features are used to train another one.